# Optimizing Geometry.STIntersect Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, gis

I am attempting to move simple Geoprocessing routines from ESRI based processes to SQL Server.  My assumption is that it will be far more efficient.  For my initial test I am working on an intersection routine to associate overlapping linear data.

In my WCASING table I have 1610 records.  I am trying to associate these Casings with their associated mains.  I have ~277,000 Mains.

I am running the query below to get a general sense of how long it will take to find individual matches.  This query returned 5 valid intersections in 40 seconds.

```
SELECT Top 5 [WCASING].[OBJECTID] As CasingOBJECTID, 
    [WPUMPPRESSUREMAIN].[OBJECTID] AS MainObjectID, [WCASING].[Shape]
FROM [dbo].[WPUMPPRESSUREMAIN]
JOIN [WCASING] 
    ON [WCASING].[Shape].STIntersects([WPUMPPRESSUREMAIN].[Shape]) = 1
```

My Primary questions;

- Will this process faster depending on the search order

  - Finding 'A' inside of 'B' vs
  - Finding 'B' inside of 'A'
  - Initial return on 5 records from these datasets is that it does not matter
- Will this process faster, if I first buffer to limit to a smaller main set and then search
- Can I use SQL Server Tuning to work with Geometry based queries

I will be working on these processes over the next few weeks.  In the meantime I would greatly appreciate insight and pointers to white papers associated with these tuning options.  Thus far I have not found a great resource.

Thank You,
Rick

Comment: It depends on a lot of things. How many points (in general) define your shapes? If it's a lot (i.e. the shapes are complex), you could benefit from trying to winnow the list down using `STBuffer()`. Also, do you have a spatial index on your Shape columns?

Comment: Also, Rob Farley just wrote a fairly extensive blog article on tuning spatial queries. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2015/04/29/tuning-slow-spatial-queries-in-sql-server.aspx

Comment: They are primarily simple lines.  Linear Features with three points or less on more than 90% of features.  No line feature defined by more then 10 points.

Comment: Yeah. The number's you're talking about (both in numbers of rows and number of points per shape) aren't crazy. Is there a spatial index on the geography columns?

Comment: On the larger table (Mains) there is a defined spatial Index.  On the smaller dataset, there is no spatial index.  I am recreating the table with an index and will retest.

Comment: Also I originally wasn't getting traction here so I cross posted to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/145019/optimizing-geometry-stintersect-query.